# change the value in reduced matrix pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe

I'm trying to implement algorithm, where given matrix(matrix represents cities) should be reduced by condition:

here the matrix(data frame matrix):

```
          0      1     2     3      4
    0  9992      1     0     2      0
    1     2  99991     5     0      0
    2     0      4  9992     0      1
    3     3      0     1  9991      2
    4     1      0     2     2  99989
```

then by a condition I delete 0-row and 2-column in the matrix , so i get this:

```
df = df.drop(2,axis=1)
df = df.drop(0,axis=0)
reducedMatrix=df
    print reducedMatrix
                   0      1     3      4
                1  2  99991     0      0
                2  0      4     0      1
                3  3      0  9991      2
                4  1      0     2  99989
```

and after deletion I should change the number of (2,0) element to a large number like 9999, I do :

```
reducedMatrix[2][0]=9999
```

but get the error

```
File "", line 81, in <module>
    reducedMatrix[2][0]=999
  File "", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 303, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6610)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 309, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6554)
KeyError: 2
```

it's imortant to save cols and rows names, because after deletion row i and col j I should change value in j,i position in the new matrix
the expected output:

```
print reducedMatrix
               0      1     3      4
            1  2      99991 0      0
            2  9999   4     0      1
            3  3      0     9991   2
            4  1      0     2      99989
```

how to avoid it?
thx

Comment: Can you try: `reducedMatrix.set_value(2, 0, 9999)`?

Comment: @NickilMaveli I tried this and that worked! Thanks a lot, saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) what you want?

```
reducedMatrix.loc[2][0] = 9999
```

where loc is used to index by label.

If you instead want to index by the new row/col *positions*, you want:

```
reducedMatrix.iloc[2][0] = 9999
```

(see [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html))

Comment: no, i have matrix after reduction and I want to set reducedMatrix[2][0] to 9999. After printing I have matrix with column names  0      1     3      4 and row names 1 2 3 4, so setting (2,0) value needed

Comment: when you say reducedMatrix[2][0], you mean the third row and first column? or the row 2 and column 0?

Comment: Feel you could write it as `reducedMatrix.iloc[2,0] = 9999` and get it to work.